# How to solve : (y^2-2xy+y)dx= (-x^2-x+2xy)dy

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(y^2-2xy+y)dx= (-x^2-x+2xy)dy$$

**UPD : So, I found the integrating factor.It's (xy)^(-4/3). Then dM/dy = dN/dx.After that the standard solution**

I tried to solve with many methods but nothing worked

my attempt:
$$(y^2-2xy+y)dx+(x^2-2xy+x)dy=0 $$ (divide by $(xy)^2$)

So that

$${(ydx+xdy)\over (xy)^2}+{dx\over x^2}+{dy\over y^2}-{2d(x+y)\over xy}=0$$

and

$${-d(xy)\over(xy)^2}+{d(x+y)\over xy}+{2d(x+y)\over xy}=0$$

Comment: Which all methods did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: i tried to find the integrating factor and also simplify. I was able to simplify to d((x+y)/(xy))+2d(x+y)/(xy)-d(xy)/(xy)^2 = 0

Comment: But whatever details you have, you should try and put in the question to avoid downvotes and potential closing.

Comment: Have a look at [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I'll help you with your mathematical expressions.

Comment: @Moo: I have such a task at the university

Comment: But check the signs once. I feel there may be some mistakes in the signs.